# Bat file and labels

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I am trying to write a bat file for a network policy that will install a program if it doesn't exist as well as several other functions. I am using GOTO statements depending on whether or not certain criterion are met. However, it seems that the labels are not firing correctly as all of them do.

I have simplified my script so as to grasp some idea of what may be happening.

```
@echo off


IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (GOTO :EXISTING) ELSE GOTO :MISSING

:EXISTING
echo file exists

:MISSING
echo file missing

ping localhost -n 5 >NUL
```

Basically it checks to see that the file "test.txt" exists in folder "c:\test" which id does. So it should echo file exists to the console. However, both "file exists" and "file missing" are echoed to the console. I find that if I remove the file from the folder or simply rename it, it only echoes "file missing"

Why is it running running both labels?

Comment: You wrote here a `switch` without `break` 's.

Comment: you're treating `GOTO` as if it were a `function()` call, which it's not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because a GOTO is just a jump in execution to a point in the script, then execution continues sequentially from that point. If you want it to stop after running 'EXISTING', then you need to do something like this. Note the extra GOTO and new label:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (GOTO :EXISTING) ELSE GOTO :MISSING

:EXISTING
echo file exists
goto :NEXTBIT

:MISSING
echo file missing

:NEXTBIT
ping localhost -n 5 >NUL
```

It's worth noting though that with cmd.exe (i.e., the NT-based command shells [NT, Win2k, XP, etc]), you can do IF...ELSE blocks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (
    ECHO File exists
) ELSE (
    ECHO File missing
)
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
```

...so you can eliminate your GOTOs entirely.

Comment: i don't think `localhost` can handle 5 pints

Comment: @jncpl ... beer powered computer? Or beer powered programming? :-) Typo fixed, ta.

Comment: @Joey ... ta, fixed. Haven't touched NT4 in years, nor have an NT4 box so couldn't go back that far in time.

Comment: what if im using goto in a for loop, how do i return to loop instead of going to :end ? 
for /L %%i IN (1,1,45) do call :docopy %%i
goto end

Answer (score 2):

It's because you need to skip over the "missing" bit if it exists:

```
    @echo off

    IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (GOTO :EXISTING) ELSE GOTO :MISSING

:EXISTING
    echo file exists
    goto :COMMON

:MISSING
    echo file missing

:COMMON
    ping localhost -n 5 >NUL
```

You may also want to keep in mind that the current `cmd.exe` batch language is a fair bit more powerful than that which came with MS-DOS. I would prefer this one:

```
@echo off
if exist c:\test\test.txt (
    echo file exists
) else (
    echo file missing
)
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
```

Answer (score 1):

After you echo file exists the next command is

```
echo file missing
```

You need to do something to skip the missing case. Perhaps another goto to a :PING label?

When you're debugging it helps to keep the echo on.

Answer (score 1):

Because `GOTO` statement moves the execution to that label. To use it in the situation like yours, you need to add another `GOTO` label.

```
@echo off

IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (GOTO :EXISTING) ELSE GOTO MISSING

:EXISTING
echo file exists
GOTO END

:MISSING
echo file missing
GOTO END

:END
ping localhost -n 5 >NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "c:\test\test.txt" ( :: warning double quotes

GOTO EXISTING
) ELSE (                      :: this format best in batch
GOTO MISSING
)                             :: don't forget

:EXISTING
echo file exists
goto OTHER                    :: if file exist jump OTHER

:MISSING
echo file missing
                              :: label is not required
:OTHER
timeout /t 5 >nul
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

u can simply

```
@echo off


IF EXIST c:\test\test.txt (GOTO :EXISTING) ELSE GOTO :MISSING

:EXISTING
  echo file exists
goto :eof
rem eof means end of file

:MISSING
  echo file missing
goto :eof

ping localhost -n 5 >NUL`enter code here`
```